# Excel 2013 - macro to automatically split data into different workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, macros

We have a large amount of data in Excel 2013 which we would like to split into multiple Excel workbooks each containing 1000 records.

So for a total of 5000 records in one workbook, we would like to run a macro which will automatically split the workbook into an additional 5 workbooks each with 1000 records. The original workbook to remain containing the original 5000 records of data.

Can anyone assist?

Many thanks

Comment: What have you already tried?  [so] isn't a free code writing service, but we are happy to help you to fix whatever you have already tried/coded/written that isn't working :)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If I understand you want to create new workbooks and copy the next 1000 lines of your original workbook into them until you have reached the number of lines in the original workbook. In this case 5 new workbooks with each 1000 lines. I can suggest paths to get you started, but not write the entire code for you!

Comment: Record a macro, have a go at amending the resultant code to your needs then come back with a specific problem and post the code if you're still stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume each record is on one row, the last column is T, and that your table has no headers.

```
Public Sub Split_wb()

Dim i as integer, arr as variant, wb as variant, ws_source as worksheet

set ws_source = activesheet

For i =1 to 5
    arr = ws_source.range("A" & i*1000-999 & ":T" & i*1000)

    set wb = workbooks.add
    wb.sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
    set arr = Nothing
next

end sub
```

Comment: If this answer helped you please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Accepting an answer rewards the contributor and helps other people with the same problem to find the correct answer.  I see you have six open questions, some around a year old.  Please review these.